# Question about generating function of kind of fibonacci partial sum

Tags: generating-functions, fibonacci-numbers

$F_n$ here is $n$-th fibonacci number
We know that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{k=0}^n F_kF_{n-k}\right)x^n$$
is a generating function of multiplying two G.F: $a_n =\langle F_n \rangle$ and $b_n = \langle F_n \rangle $

I was messing with this, googling, reading and stuff and i came across question about generating function of
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{k=0}^n F_{2k}F_{n-k}\right)x^n$$
(Only difference is $F_k$ and $F_{2k}$)

I know there is one nice equation
$$F_{2n} = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} F_{2i+1}$$
But when i plug it in, it becomes a little too messy and complicated.

I'd love to get some help on this question. Thanks

Comment: If you have a closed-form expression for $\sum_{n=0}^\infty F_n x^n$ and another for $\sum_{n=0}^\infty F_{2n} x^n$, then this is their product.

Comment: Hint: Let $f$ be the ordinary generating function of $F_n$.  Then what does $f(x) + f(-x)$ give you?

Comment: Nice, thanks for your answers. 
if F(x) is generating function of $F_n$ then 
$\dfrac12(F(x)+F(-x))$ seems to be generating function of $F_{2n}$, so generating function from my question is in fact $F(x)*\dfrac12(F(x)+F(-x))$, i hope i didn't mess it up. 

Thank you guys for your answers, that's a nice trick to know :)

Comment: Careful!  $\frac{1}{2}(F(x) + F(-x)) = \sum_{n \geq 0} F_{2n} x^{2n}$.  I think you really want $\sum_{n \geq 0} F_{2n} x^n$.  (Note the $x^{2n}$ vs. $x^n$).  Also, feel free to post your answer below (as an answer, not a comment) so we can have a look at it.

Comment: Oh, you are right. 
Is there a way to change $\sum_{n=0}^\infty F_{2n}x^{2n}$ into $\sum_{n=0}^\infty F_{2n}x^n$? cause i can't simply divide it by $x^n$?

Comment: nvm my question: 
We want every $2n$ term to be in place of $n$, so we have to divide by $x^2$ not $x^n$ (dumb of me). 
Am i missing something now? If not, i will complete my answer as soon as i wake up tommorow :-) 
Thanks for your help

Comment: @Chris: Yes, do post your answer.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, hello, thanks.
I completed it, but now i have different question.

We know $$A(x)=(1+x)^r= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{r}{n} x^n$$
And $$B(x)=(1+x^2)^r= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{r}{n} x^{2n}$$

so $$A(x)B(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{r}{k} \binom{r}{n-2k}x^n$$
Why can we do that? 
Why we don't have to make $B(x)$ equal $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{r}{n} x^n$ first? 
I'd appreciate some help on this example too(but i didnt feel like posting another question)

Comment: @Chris: You have to, actually.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, thanks for answer.
Please correct me if i'm wrong, but here we have exponential generating function $EA(x)$
and it's equal to $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{r^{\underline k}}{k!}x^{2k}$$
I know taking deriverative for $x$ of $EA(x)$ will move whole sequence one to the left, so taking k-th derivative of it will give us $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{r^{\underline {2k}}}{(2k!)}x^k$$ And now we can apply it right? Is my thinking ok?

Comment: @Chris, post your other question as a proper question. It deserves separate discussion.

Comment: Ok, thanks, i posted new question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so to get generating function $G(x)$ of $a_n = \langle F_{2n} \rangle$ we can perform a little trick on generating function $F(x)$ of $\langle F_n \rangle$
It is, $F(x)+F(-x)$ will count 2 times even-indexed elements and 0 times odd-indexed elements, so we have to divide it by 2, so our $$G(x)=\dfrac12(F(x)+F(-x))=\frac{x^2}{(1-x-x^2)(1+x-x^2)}$$
But let's notice that $$G(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty F_{2n} x^{2n}$$
but we want $G(x)$ to be equal to $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty F_{2n} x^n$$
To do it, just divide every term by $x^{1/2}$ and we get
$$G(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty F_{2n} x^n = \frac{x}{(1-\sqrt{x}-x)(1+\sqrt{x}-x)}=\frac{x}{1-3x+x^2}$$

And our answer will be $$G(x)F(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (\sum_{k=0}^n F_{2k}F_{n-k}) x^n$$

Comment: Dividing every term by $x^2$ doesn't change $x^{2n}$ to $x^n$; it only shifts terms by $2$. You have to change $x$ to $\sqrt{x}$ instead.

Comment: oh! you are so right! And finally i got right function. Thank you very much :-)